# Make a text field accept only numeric values in APEX

Tags: oracle, validation, oracle-apex

I have an APEX app that I am working on and need to make a field to only accept numeric values.

I want to have a validation that displays "Only numeric values allowed" whenever the user inputs letters or other characters that are not numeric.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `translate` function, you can "detect" whether string contains something but digits (this example allows decimal dot as well):

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '1234' from dual union all  --   valid
  3     select '12a4' from dual union all  -- invalid
  4     select '12.4' from dual union all  --   valid
  5     select 'abcd' from dual union all  -- invalid
  6     select '1#34' from dual            -- invalid
  7    )
  8  select col, translate(col, 'x0123456789.', 'x') result
  9  from test;

COL  RESU
---- ----
1234
12a4 a
12.4
abcd abcd
1#34 #

SQL>
```

So, if the result is `NULL`, then it is a valid value.

In Apex, you'd create validation (function that returns error text) which looks like this:

```
if translate(:P1_ITEM, 'x0123456789.', 'x') is not null then
   return 'Only numeric values allowed';
else
   return null;
end;
```

Comment: When I run the application, I still don't get any validation as expected. What I did was adding a validation of type "function that returns error text" with your code and adding my item of course.

Comment: A validation in apex only fires on page submit. If you want the validation to fire on change of the item you need to do a dynamic action.

Answer (score 0):

These field definitions are more about the inherent server-side validations that will run on your behalf to ensure the data submitted is numeric.

I think the best you're going to get is having some client side validation *as well* that gives the user immediate feedback - either has message, or auto-strip. I'm not sure if you can [force a HTML element](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-force-input-field-to-enter-numbers-only-using-javascript/) to only allow numerics.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to validate after each new character, you can try to add Dynamic Action based on `Key Release` event and `Execute JavaScript code` when true. Something like this

```
if (   $v("P2_NEW") !== ""
    && isNaN($v("P2_NEW"))) {
  alert("Not a number");
}
```

Comment: What I understood from your solution suggestion and applying(Add dynamic action with your event and code). I still don't have an alert popping up when I enter letters in the numeric field.

Comment: 1 create DA on your field (event - key released), 2 add true action (type - execute JS code), 3 put example code into action and change field name to your.

Comment: I added a picture to the post, applying the steps you just mentioned but no luck still.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some hours of trying this and that, the following is what has worked for me.

1. Click in the page. In the "Function and Global Variable Declaration" section add this code:

```
function isInputNumber(evt){
                
                var ch = String.fromCharCode(evt.which);
                
                if(!(/[0-9]/.test(ch))){
                    evt.preventDefault();
                }
                
            }
```

2. In the "Page HTML Body Attribute" section add this code:

```
onkeypress="isInputNumber(event)"
```

and thats it. This will prevent the user from entering letters into the input field.